# yii and non database models

Tags: oop, yii

I need some help as I seem not to be able to grasp the concept.

In a framework, namely `Yii`, we create models that correspond to `database tables`. We extend them from `CActiveRecord`.

However, if I want to create a class that will get some data from other models but then will do all the computations based on those results and do something with them... then how do I proceed?

I want to clearly divide the responsibility so I don't want put all the calculations in source db based models. Basically the idea is that it will be taking some stuff from some models and then updating another models with the results of the calculations.

What do I do?

- Keep all the calculations in some controller and use required models? (Hesitant about this because there is a rule to keep controller slim)
- Create a none db model and then work from there (how?)?
- Do something else (what?)?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For you to use the Yii **interpretation** of Model, you will have to create class, which depends on [`CModel`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel). It is an abstract class, thus you will be required to implement [`attributeNames()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#attributeNames-detail) method.

To use other "Models" with this new structure, you will need to inject them in constructor, or right after your custom model has been created.

---

In real MVC model is a layer, which mostly contains two sets of classes with specific responsibilities: domain business logic and data access operations. Objects which are responsible for Domain Business Logic have no clue where the information is stored and where it comes from. Or even if there is such a thing as "database".

This video might explain a bit: https://vimeo.com/21173483

Comment: Great video resource! Will check it out. Thanks!

Comment: @RandomWhiteTrash , you can [download slides here](http://qafoo.com/talks/11_11_osidays_advanced_oo_patters.pdf).